# Rob J Hyndman's Arima function in R vs SARIMAX in python

Tags: python, r, arima, sarimax

I am trying to replicate results of the Hyndman's R version of Arima function with SARIMAX function in Python, but the coefficients are not matching given the same dataset.

R code:

```r
md1 = Arima(y, xreg = as.matrix(df[,c('x1', 'x2'), drop = False]), order = c(1,0,1), include mean = TRUE)
```

Python code:

```py
md2 = SARIMAX(y, exog = df[np.array(['x1', 'x2']), trend = 'c', mle_regression = True)
```

Comment: Did you figure out the reason? I am having the same issue

Comment: Didn't dig deeper but got the results close to the R version using statsmodels arima with method = 'innovations_mle'

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have tried different methods and  I got the results closer to R. But I need exact values. Not sure if it is possible though.  I haven't used the method you mentioned. I will try it too. Thanks again